# Identify the equivalence relation on a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be the set of all points in the $x - y$ plane. Define a
relation $\sim$ on A as follows:

> For $a, b\in A$, $a\sim b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ have the same distance from the origin. Is $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $A$?

Comment: what have you tried? Can you describe algebraically your relation, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an equivalence relation, because it satisfies

- **reflexivity:** a point $a \in A$ has the same distance from the origin as itself;
- **symmetry:** if $a$ and $b$ have the same distance from the origin, so do $b$ and $a$.
- **transitivity:** if $a$ and $b$ have the same distance from the origin and $b$ and $c$ have the same distance from the origin, then $a$ and $c$ have the same distance from the origin.